# Doubt in proof of Tychonoff theorem

Tags: general-topology

I read the proof of the Tychonoff theorem from Munkres' Topology, a first course.

In the last line of proof, it says that

"every basis element of $X$, containing $x$ intersects with every element of $ \mathcal{D} $ hence $ x \in \overline{D}$ for all $ D \in \mathcal{D}$ ".

Here I could prove

"For topological space $(X, \tau)$, if $ y \in X$ and $ A \subset X $ with $ A \cap V = \varnothing $ for all neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$"

Using fact $ \overline{A} = A \cup \partial A$

But the problem here is the neighbourhood is not necessarily an open set(or basis element).

Comment: That fact you could prove (with $\neq$ instead of $=$) is in fact a proposition in Munkres itself. So there is no need for  an extra proof. And the neighbourhood mentioned in that line of the proof is in fact open, so I don't understand the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement that you want to prove I assume that you mean that $A\cap V\color{red}{\ne}\varnothing$ for each nbhd $V$ of $x$. It suffices to prove that if $A\cap V\ne\varnothing$ for each open nbhd $V$ of $x$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, since if every nbhd of $x$ intersects $A$, then certainly every open nbhd of $x$ intersects $A$, and certainly every basis element containing $x$ intersects $A$. And if every open nbhd of $x$ intersects $A$, then certainly every basis element containing $x$ intersects $A$, so it suffices to prove the result that Munkres is actually using:

> If $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $X$, $x\in X$, $A\subseteq X$, and $B\cap A\ne\varnothing$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ that contains $x$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$.

Using the characterization $\operatorname{cl}A=A\cup\operatorname{bdry}A$ is an awkward way to prove it, but such a proof is possible. Suppose that $x\notin A\cup\operatorname{bdry}A$. Since $x\notin\operatorname{bdry}A$, $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that either $U\cap A=\varnothing$, or $U\setminus A=U\cap(X\setminus A)=\varnothing$. If $U\setminus A=\varnothing$, then $x\in U\subseteq A$, contradicting the fact that $x\notin A$, so $U\cap A=\varnothing$. $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $X$, so there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$, and clearly $B\cap A=\varnothing$. That is, we’ve shown that if $x\notin\operatorname{cl}A$, then there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\cap A=\varnothing$, so of course the contrapositive is also true: if $B\cap A\ne\varnothing$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ containing $x$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$.

By the way, for many of us *neighborhood* **means** *open neighborhood* unless the contrary is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the problem is,  but every open set  (and so every basic set) is a neighborhood.   Not conversely.

Recall that a neighborhood of a point is any set which contains an open set containing that point.   That's  $\mathscr N_x $ is a neighborhood of  $x $ if and only if there's an open set  $U $ such that  $x\in U\subset\mathscr N_x $.